# Pytube Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, youtube-api, pytube

I've been trying to use the Pytube module and every time I use its Client attribute it keeps coming up with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    client = pytube.Client('my-app-identifier')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Client'
```

Comment: Sounds like the `pytube` object doesn't have a `Client` attribute. Are you using a tutorial or documentation that implies that it does? Got a link?

Comment: I am using the documentation heres the links: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytube/5.1.0 https://pytube.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html

Comment: Are you sure that the documentation from your second link is for the library in your first link? The docs seem to be written by "Noah Silas" and the library by "Nick Ficano". Isn't it possible that they're two unrelated projects that happen to share a name?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the [latest version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytube) of `pytube` (which gets installed with `pip install pytube` is today the version [6.1.5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytube/6.1.5); so you should probably be looking at that version's PyPI page instead. The brief documentation on the PyPI page says nothing about the `Client` class; instead the main API class is `YouTube`, as shown in this excerpt:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ik-RsDGPI5Y")

# Once set, you can see all the codec and quality options YouTube has made
# available for the perticular video by printing videos.

pprint(yt.get_videos())
```

---

The "PyTube" documentation at [Read the Docs](https://pytube.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) seems to be for [a completely unrelated project](https://github.com/noahsilas/PyTube). As far as I can see, this project is not available on PyPI.

Answer (score 3):

- The [“PyTube documentation”](https://pytube.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html) you are looking at is for the **PyTube**, a library written by Noah Silas and Kai Powell, available on [GitHub](https://github.com/noahsilas/PyTube). The library hasn’t been updated in 5 years, and with YouTube’s many changes, it’s likely that it will no longer work.
- The **pytube** library available from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytube) is a completely different library written by Nick Ficano and does not really come with a lot of documentation. Instead, the only manual is on the [GitHub project page](https://github.com/nficano/pytube).